# evohtmltopdf.dll Images are not rendered in the pdf

Tags: html-to-pdf, evopdf

If the image src attribute refers to image folder then it gets rendered in the pdf file.
If the src attribute refers to an internal url then the image is not rendered.
The other image is stored in the database that is why I need to specify the url.

Do I need to specify the complete path in the src attribute of the image?

Or the pdf engine will be able to extract the image like the browser is able to?

I have the following html which I send to the converter:

Relevant Snippet….

```
<div class="span12">

<img src="AccessPoint.aspx?action=Report.EditRecord.Start&html=TestUpload.html&script=Show&no_transaction=true&fileid=69">

<img src="images/imgWordDoc.gif">

</div>
```

I use the following code to generate the pdf:

```
                 // byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(html.ToString());

                 // send the PDF document as a response to the browser for download        



                 //response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");

                 string strFileName = "PrintToPDF.pdf";

                 if (template_defaults["PDF_REPORT_NAME"] != null)

                       strFileName = template_defaults["PDF_REPORT_NAME"].ToString() + ".pdf";



                 response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",

                       "attachment; filename=" + strFileName + ";size=" + pdfBytes.Length.ToString());

                 response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

                 response.Flush();

                 response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);

                 m_error_log.WriteLine("pdf html = " + html.ToString(), iErrorLog.TITLE2);

                 response.Flush();
```

Comment: Do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.evopdf.com/support.aspx:

> **Q: When I convert a HTML string to PDF, the external CSS files and images are not applied in the rendered PDF document.**
>
> A: When you convert a HTML string referencing external CSS files and
>   images by relative URLs, the converter cannot determine the full URLs.
>   In order to solve this you have to set the baseURL parameter of the
>   HTML string conversion method with the full URL of the page from where
>   you have retrieved the HTML string. As an alternative you can manually
>   insert a BASE tag in the HEAD tag of the HTML page as in the example
>   below or use full URLs in the HTML string:
>
> ```
>           <HEAD> <BASE HREF="SiteURL"> </HEAD>
> ```

This works for me.
If images are with `href="../Images/Footer.png"`, I added a

```
<base href="https:// mysite .com/Images/" />
```

(without spaces)

Comment: I am trying to use EvoPdf library. I have html string with a full path to an image.